# Unable to click anything after closing Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which I open via javascript:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('.modal-content').load("page.html");
```

In order to close the modal, I trigger this code:

```
$("div#myModal.modal.fade").trigger("click");
```

My problem is that when the modal is closed, nothing in the page can be clicked again.

Any ideas?

Comment: use `.hide()`, or `.modal('hide')`

Comment: Can you show the full code please ?

Comment: In Simple English, If you are manually trigger the click event for close the modal. some events and css rules could be not working properly. So bootstrap already provide the method for hide the modal box as well. you just use .modal('hide').

Syntax like that

$('your element id').modal('hide')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is because you're only hiding the modal UI, you're not clearing the overlay behind the modal which catches mouse events and stops them.

To do what you require, use Bootstrap's built in method for closing the modal instead of triggering the click on the `.fade` element:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I have tried it before asking the question. The div that's not clickable has fixed position located at bottom:0px. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: In which case please add a working example to your question. This should work absolutely fine.

Comment: nvm fixed it. thanks for the help anyway. I had 2 nested divs and i had set the selector in the parent div and when the modal closes, it was not recognised for some reason. I moved the selector to the inner div now

Answer (score 0):

> .modal('hide')
>
> Manually hides a modal. Returns to the caller before the modal has
>   actually been hidden (i.e. before the hidden.bs.modal event occurs).

why not closing the modal in the same way you opened

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```